# execute a shell command in nodejs

Tags: node.js, shell

Am trying to execute following shell command in nodejs script.it is working fine in terminal

```
    find -type f -printf %T+\t%p\n | sort -n
```

node script

```
 var command = ' cd ~/home'
              command +=' find -type f -printf %T+\t%p\n | sort -n'
        exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {       


    });
```

while executing the above code am getting

```
exec error: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
```

How can i solve this eroor

Comment: Double up the back slash characters.

Comment: means....can u please chnage my code..i didnt get u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double up the back slashs:

```
command +='find -type f -printf %T+\\t%p\\n | sort -n'
```